# How to wait till the prompt comes, when using 'subprocess' interactive method?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am using below code, to handle user interactive commands. Means when I enter command "command x", I need to enter/input 'test123' when the prompt comes.

Python code:

```
import subprocess
p=subprocess.Popen("C:\test\command x",
    stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    universal_newlines=True)
p.stdin.write("test123")
result_first_line=p.stdout.readline()
```

Now the problem is, when I enter 'command x', the expected prompt comes after 10-15 seconds.

Is it possible to insert sleep to wait for prompt in this code?

Comment: You want to wait even longer than the 10-15 seconds for the prompt to appear?

Comment: @martineau Sometimes YES. Approximately I need to wait 10 to 15 seconds to get prompt.

Comment: Sorry, guess, I don't understand your question. Seems like you could just sleep for 10-15 seconds after starting the the other process before doing anything else. What happens now and when/where exactly to you want the sleeping to occur?